# Jackson @JsonProperty not working if property name not equal field name

Tags: java, json, annotations, jackson

I have following JSON

```
{
  "known-name": "Zevs",
  "approximate-age": 320
}
```

And binding class

```
public class GodBinding {

  @JsonProperty("known-name")
  public String name;

  @JsonProperty("approximate-age")
  public int age;

  // constructors
  // getters & setters
}
```

And followng maven dependencies
     
          2.23.2
          2.5.4

```
 <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
 </dependencies>
```

If I post such json then I have unexpected result with null's.

```
GodBinding [name=null, age=0]
```

If I use @JsonProperty without names and send JSON where property names equal field names

```
{
  "name": "Zevs",
  "age": 320
}
```

then it's working fine

```
GodBinding [name=Zevs, age=320]
```

If somebody know, how to make @JsonProperty("name") on fields working correctly?

Comment: @JsonProperty("anyname") annotation ignore any given name and tryies to bind data by field name only.

Comment: None of the provided solutions helped me. Using jackson version 2.9.4. What else could be the reason for the annotation not working?

Answer (score 6):

This is often caused when the annotations of Jackson is of Jackson 1, but you want to use Jackson 2, as mentioned in many other questions.

In my case, in the project I have another dependency which was imported wrongly:

```
import org.testcontainers.shaded.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
```

when I create the `ObjectMapper`. I guess `testcontainers` uses its own `ObjectMapper` as its dependency and exposed it incorrectly; actually it is an older version. Not sure which is.

I change it to

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
```

and all works now. This is what I call "first level dependency", not "dependency of dependency". In my gradle file it is version 2.3.

I mention this because:

- I see other questions only mentioning the confusion between Jackson 1 and 2, not this of `testcontainer`. We just must ignore those not of `fasterxml.jackson`.
- Pay attention of the version not only of `@JsonProperty`, etc, **but also the version of Jackson you use when importing `ObjectMapper` and `DeserializationFeature`.**

Comment: this was exactly my problem as well

Answer (score 0):

You should add this to your POM

```xml
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.4</version>
</dependency>
```

you can see an example [here](http://buraktas.com/convert-objects-to-from-json-by-jackson-example/)

Comment: jackson-databind already were because of jackson-jaxrs-json-provider.

Comment: For given example You have equal json property name and object field name. name or lastName for example. That is why - no problems.

Comment: No, if jackson is exposed as the dependency of some other dependency, it may be a wrong version and it will not work probably, which is my case. We should only use `fasterxml.jackson`. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

*Just for reference*, I fixed this same issue by importing explicitly the [`com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.9.9`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.9.9) instead of using the `ObjectMapper` **indirectly** imported by other packages.

---

Hints:

1. import the right dependency;
2. import from the right dependency;